# Qual a origem da palavra "esferovite"? Ainda é usada em Portugal? Esse material é conhecido por algum outro nome?

Tags: origem-histórica, diferenças-transatlânticas, uso-mais-comum

Como é que *Isopor* veio a se chamar "Esferovite" em Portugal?

O Priberam define [**Esferovite**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/esferovite)  como "espuma de polistireno, material muito leve usado especialmente como isolante e no fabrico de embalagens (ex.: caixa de esferovite).

Aos meus ouvidos, *esferovite* soa como um nome de doença.

- O que houve com a Lúcia?
- Ah, ela está com esferovite.

Comment: *Nunca tinhas óbido falar de [esferóbite](https://forvo.com/word/esferovite/#pt)? G'anda estranja...* :)

Comment: @ANeves   óbido? G'anda estranja?  Falamos a mesma língua?

Comment: @Centaurus coitada da Lúcia, nunca mais vou olhar para ela da mesma maneira :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tanto em Portugal como no Brasil o [poliestireno expandido](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poliestireno), ou espuma de poliestireno, se tornou popularmente conhecido pelo nome de empresas que o comercializavam:

- **Esferovite** é uma marca registada, da empresa "Representações Esferovite, Lda.", [fundada](https://www.esferovite.pt/30-a-empresa) em Lisboa em 1960 e ainda em atividade.
- **Isopor**, também uma marca registrada, ganhou seu nome da firma "Isopor - Indústria e Comércio de Plásticos S. A.", de São Bernardo do Campo, fundada provavelmente também nos anos 1960, [comprada](https://www.basf.com/global/en/who-we-are/history/BASF-History-in-Figures.html) pela alemã BASF em 1968 e [vendida](https://www.mundoisopor.com.br/conheca-a-historia-do-isopor) em 1998 à também alemã [Knauf](https://www.knauf-isopor.com.br/corporativo/quem-somos/).

Esses termos ainda estão em uso, sendo encontrados em dicionários, com a Infopédia explicitamente [afirmando](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/esferovite) que esferovite se trata da

> designação corrente da espuma de polistireno

Comment: O nome "isopor" é conhecido em Portugal?

Comment: Imagino que não seja muito conhecido, @Centaurus, assim como eu também nunca tinha ouvido falar de esferovite antes da tua pergunta, e também porque o Priberam e a Infopédia qualificam o verbete isopor como brasileiro.

Comment: Nunca ouvi falar de isopor, cá por Portugal. (Nem de poliestireno.)